# Javascript: compute the radius of circle given center point and another point

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

Suppose I have a circle with a center point at origin (0,0) and a 90deg point from it at (0,10)... from this 2 obvious points the radius of the circle would definitely be `10`, right?

I researched that the formula of finding the radius based on center point and another point is:

```
Math.sqrt( ((x1-x2)*2)  + ((y1-y2)*2) )
```

but I'm getting a value of `4.47213595499958` instead of what I thought would be `10`.

Can anyone teach me the correct formula I should use to make a perfect circle from a center point to another point?

Comment: Isn't 90deg `(10,0)`? I thought 0deg was pointing up.

Comment: Generally speaking, with cartesian systems the common interpretation of zero degrees is pointing to the right

Comment: @slebetman Yes I'm probably too sleepy.. with css3 gradients which just changed the vendor-prefixed 0deg pointing to the right to the now standard 0deg pointing up I'm probably mixing this with basic Cartesian plane as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Power in javascript is done by using `Math.pow`:

```
Math.sqrt( Math.pow((x1-x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1-y2), 2) )
```

Comment: wow. i would definitely use this formula... thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5):

In javascript, the `*` operator means multiply, not raise to the power. The correct formula should be:

```
Math.sqrt( ((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)) + ((y1-y2)*(y1-y2)) )
```

Comment: You could also use the `^` operator (which does mean "raise to the power"): `Math.sqrt( ((x1-x2)^2) + ((y1-y2)^2) )`

Comment: @pete No, it most certainly does not. It is the binary XOR operator.

Comment: @pete That is a binary bitwise XOR operator. Oh Xymos already said that.

Comment: My mistake (thinking in VB, right now). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: thanks guys! i appreciate your help! thanks for making me realize the stupid mistake i made. I should have used Math.pow instead of just multiplying it to 2.